# GCP Kubernetes: Cannot pull image - pods died suddenly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We experienced a major outage with our production systems today. Without any user interaction most of the kubernetes pods went down with a "ImagePullBackOff" error message.

We had to manually restart builds and repush all images. I verified that in the container registry the referred images exist - this is the case, there was no change done. Even with images being displayed as avaliable, we had to repush them to get rid of the error.

What happened there?!

[Example error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3D9z.jpg)

**EDIT**
Docker is unable to find the image.

```
$ docker pull eu.gcr.io/seepex-cs/scs-grafana
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from seepex-cs/scs-grafana
9d48c3bd43c5: Already exists 
4842084dac50: Already exists 
7cbaa73b9ead: Already exists 
9a7207a7a1b5: Already exists 
6bb6df97bf66: Already exists 
e9c24addd21e: Already exists 
21ae065ef1d6: Already exists 
error pulling image configuration: unknown blob
```

Image is listed in google container registry:

[image]

Comment: You might need to [describe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-finding-resources) the pod to see an actual reason why it cannot pull an image. You might also need to check the troubleshooting guide about [ImagePullBackOff](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#ImagePullBackOff) to get more insight on this. Similar situation discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52040077/how-to-debug-imagepullbackoff-on-gcr-io) as well. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Since I wanted to save space and money, i´ve setup cleanup jobs for the eu.artifacts.*project*.appspot.com bucket together with other buckets. This is the bucket where the registry artifacts are stored. After 30 days some of the less active services were auto-deleted...